# Register variant sandbox while performing build

Tags: mks

How do we register variant sandbox while performing the build?

While running the below cmd we are getting error:

```
si resync --noconfirm -f -R --sandbox=/builds/wcbd/sandbox18/eCommerce/workspace/WCBD/project.pj --hostname=ryew3mks1.na.avonet.net --port=7001


*** MKS125216: The sandbox file /builds/wcbd/sandbox18/eCommerce/workspace/WCBD/project.pj is not registered with the system.

si createsandbox -R  --hostname=ryew3mks1.na.avonet.net  --port=7001   --devpath
=SMT_DEVPATH_03MAR2015_REL_2.0
```

The above script doesn't give any response.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

resync command is used to re synchronize the code in already created sandbox. so better create a new sandbox every time you build your code.

Syntax to create sandbox:

```
si createsandbox -R -Y --user=replaceusernametoconnecttorepo  --password="password" --hostname=givehostname --port=enterport --project="projectpath" "SANDBOXNAME OR Foldername"
```